# How do I limit my Windows application to spawning a single instance of a process?

Tags: c#

I am working on a Windows application. I have created a help file (.chm) using a third party tool and I call it from the Windows application. The help file is invoked successfully when I click on *Help* menu item or press <kbd>F1</kbd> for the application.

The problem I am facing is that if I click on the menu item again or press <kbd>F1</kbd> (while the application is open and I have not closed the previous help file) it opens another instance of the help file.

Let me be clear by giving an example: I want it to be just like the "Solitaire" game. No matter how many times you press <kbd>F1</kbd> or the *Contents* menu item it shows only one help window.

I want to do same thing like "Solitaire". I don't want multiple instances to be created.

I hope you understood my problem. Please let me know if my query is wrong.
I have posted my code below.

```
    ProcessStartInfo info;
    Process exeprocess;
```

The below code is in Help menuitem click event.

```
    private void mnuContents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         string ApplicationPath=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HelpFile"].ToString();
         info = new ProcessStartInfo(ApplicationPath);
         //Process.Start(info);
         exeprocess = Process.Start(info);
     }
```

Comment: Post the code you have to launch your help file.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is:

1. Have your application create a system-wide resource (the example below uses a Win32 mutex)
2. Check the resource before you spawn the .chm (I imagine you're probably using ShellExec or some variant to spawn the help file.

Here's example code (in C++/Win32 code):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243953

Another, different approach is to see if any currently running processes match the one you would spawn.  Here's example code for this approach:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/single-instance-windows-form

Comment: OP's problem is slightly different: He wants to make sure he only spawns one instance of a non .NET process (the .CHM reader). so instructions for how to limit your own process to one instance do not help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Process` object, so you should probably store it somewhere and check if it is still active the next time the help command is invoked.  You could use [`Process.HasExited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) for that purpose. If it has exited, clean up the `Process` object by calling `Dispose()` and then launch a new instance, storing it away again. Repeat as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is your block of code to start the CHM viewer:

```
 private void mnuContents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string ApplicationPath=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HelpFile"].ToString();
     info = new ProcessStartInfo(ApplicationPath);
     //Process.Start(info);
     exeprocess = Process.Start(info);
 }
```

in exeprocess there is a property called Id. You need to keep track of that Id for the next time the user presses F1 or the menu key.

You need to do a check like

```
 private void mnuContents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (Process.GetProcessById(self.previousId) != null) {
         string ApplicationPath=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HelpFile"].ToString();
         info = new ProcessStartInfo(ApplicationPath);
         //Process.Start(info);
         exeprocess = Process.Start(info);
         self.previousId = exeprocess.Id;
     }
 }
```

Something like that would work.  If you want to get fancy, you can bring the already-running process to the foreground as well.

Comment: May i know what is "self.previousId"..i dint understand that part

Comment: Just some variable you can use that is an `int`. You need to hold the process id of the lat time you launched the CHM file, and you need to check to see if it's still running.  That's why that variable exists.

Comment: I have tried the way you suggested but still multiple instances of CHM file is created

Comment: Tbis scheme will only work inside one instance of your main .exe.  It WON'T help if there are MULTIPLE instances of the process that SPAWNS the .chm.